# Expect and is expecting

Tags: difference, tense

This passage is from "Macmillan English Grammar in Context" by Michael Vince.

> "They are still examining the wreckage of the high speed train. They don't believe the accident involves driver error. We expect to publish an inquiry into this accident quite soon", a spokesman announced yesterday."

Should I use "expect" or "Are expecting"?

And in this sentence

> "Thanks for your email. I hope/ I am hoping to get back to you very soon."

The book says the progressive is less definite. What does it mean?

Comment: That seems like common language usage. Moreover, the simple present tense is more accurate in time sensing than the present continuous tense. To say that, I mean "are expecting" may indicate (delayed) future work in a sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Vince is saying that the progressive indicates a more tentative (less confident) hope or expectation, while the simple present indicates a more confident (more definite) hope or expectation.

The difference is fairly subtle, but I would definitely expect "expect" (simple present) in

> We expect to publish an inquiry into this accident quite soon

This one could be either:

> Thanks for your email. I hope / I am hoping to get back to you very soon

but I think Vince is right that "am hoping" sounds a bit less confident.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much. But his choice of tenses is not clear in another exercise https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/260793/present-simple-or-progressive

Comment: Could you please have a look?

Comment: "Spend" and " is working" are not correct.

Comment: Some of these things are quite difficult to explain.  I often find that both sound OK but there is a subtle difference that is hard to pin down.  I haven't been taught any more rules about this - I just have my own intuitions.  However, I have attempted an aswer.